# Meteor subscribe callback

Tags: meteor

According to this article here:

https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes

> Subscriptions don't block
>
> Many aspects of the framework seem like magic. So much so that it may
>   cause you to forget how web browsers work. Take this simple example:
>
> Meteor.subscribe('posts');
>
> var post = Posts.findOne();
>
> The idea that post will be undefined is the root cause of roughly one
>   in twenty meteor questions on stackoverflow.

So then why doesn't subscribe have a callback, and if it does, why isn't it referenced more often by the Meteor literati?

Why don't we have:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts', function(err, posts){

//when the items/posts actually arrive

});
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Maybe I don't get the question, but the Meteor.Subscribe function has callbacks named onError and onReady methods.

> Optional. May include onError and onReady callbacks. If a function is
>   passed instead of an object, it is interpreted as an onReady callback.

[From docs.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe)

For example.

```
Meteor.subscribe("posts", {
  onReady: function () { console.log("onReady And the Items actually Arrive", arguments); },
  onError: function () { console.log("onError", arguments); }
});
```

Also check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1461)

Comment: and also if you call without callback and assigned a subscription to variable , you can check the subscription ready or not using `ready()` method. example: `var handle=Meteor.subscribe('posts')` here you can check the subscription is ready or not by using `handle.ready()`  this may be one of the reasons why meteor docs doesn't use callbacks for subscriptions

Comment: I guess my point of the question is that there are too many instances of examples that just show Meteor.subscribe without the callback, why would you ever do that without the callback.

Comment: The docs don't make this clear at all and give no examples. It's unfortunately confusing.

Comment: This is bogus. You're sending `onReady` and `onError` to the publication.

Answer (score 20):

Note: I have updated the article after reading this question.

While [subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) does have an optional callback, I intentionally avoided it in the original article because there aren't currently any common patterns that use it. In other words, I didn't want readers to come away from the article thinking that callbacks were actually the right solution to this problem.

In production applications, subscriptions typically come in two flavors:

- Global: initiated as soon as the client starts, or maybe in an autorun.
- Route: initiated as via a `subscriptions` or `waitOn` [option](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#subscriptions).

It's also worth noting that in recent weeks, the [template subscription pattern](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) has emerged, though it hasn't seen wide adoption yet.

In all of these cases, the subscription is started and then can either be asynchronously checked for a reactive `ready` state, or ignored with the use of [guards](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) to prevent reference errors.

Because `ready` is reactive, this effectively gives us the same benefits of a callback, but with fewer lines of code. Let's look at two examples:

#### example 1

```js
Meteor.subscribe('posts', function() {
  Session.set('postsReady', true);
});

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Session.get('postsReady'))
    showFancyAnimation();
});
```

#### example 2

```js
var handle = Meteor.subscribe('posts');

Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (handle.ready())
    showFancyAnimation();
});
```

Both examples demonstrate the same concept - subscribing and then reactively testing the state of the subscription. As you can see there really isn't a benefit to the callback.

Finally, (as I now point out in the article), subscriptions are often spatially separated from the code which uses them. You'll typically subscribe in your route code and consume the results in your templates. For this reason you almost never see code which looks like:

```js
Meteor.subscribe('posts', function() {
  showFancyAnimation();
});
```

In fact, the only place I ever encounter code like the above is in SO answers because the author is trying to make a quick demonstration rather than trying to show a typical usage pattern.

Comment: This totally works. One question, did you wrote `this.ready()` in your publication or the 'handle.ready()' worked without it?

Comment: You don't need `this.ready()` in a publish function in order to get `handle.ready()` on the client __unless__ you are returning a falsy value in the publisher. For example if you return `undefined` in the publish function because a user isn't logged in, then `handle.ready()` would never fire on the client. Also see [this post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/this-ready-in-a-publication/1681).

Comment: I am using this pattern a react `useEffect` hook and it's working excellently. The action is dispatched in an external module which updates the global redux state.

Answer (score 12):

`Meteor.subscribe` has been enhanced since v1.2. One of its callbacks `onError` is now replaced with `onStop` in Meteor v1.2.0.2 documentation

> callbacks Function or Object
>
> Optional. May include onStop and onReady callbacks. If there is an
>   error, it is passed as an argument to onStop. If a function is passed
>   instead of an object, it is interpreted as an onReady callback.

Having that enhancement, `Meteor.subscribe` is used with callbacks as an object

```
Meteor.subscribe( 'collection', {
    onStop:  function( error /* optional */ ) {
        // when the sub terminates for any reason,
        // with an error argument if an error triggered the stop
    },
    onReady: function() {
        // when ready
    }
});
```

However, `onError` still works for backward compatibility. *Be aware that some popular packages, such as [SubsManager](https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager) still uses `onError`.* That being said such snippet below is now deprecated but doesn't break .

```
Meteor.subscribe( 'collection', {
    onError: function( error ) {
        // if the subscribe terminates with an error
    },
    onReady: function() {
        // when ready
    }
});
```

On the other hand, `Meteor.subscribe` can be used with a callback as a function as before

```
Meteor.subscribe( 'collection', function() {
    // when ready
});
```

As my personal notice, if `Meteor.subscribe` happens to be passed with careless multiple callback functions, only the last one takes effect as the `onReady` callback.

```
Meteor.subscribe( 'collection', function() {
    // this doesn't execute.
}, function() {
    // when ready.
});
```

The associated Git commitment is listed [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/085e02d525157905feb59b9dccd42765733f1667#diff-49661597d8aba55cb23024fb8ea9e7edL481) for a reference.

Comment: and how can i get the result of the subscriptions? arguments come empty now