# Trigger global meteor subscription without iron router

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, iron-router, subscribe

This should be an easy one.

Here's what I would like:

**Page 1**: *Subscribe to 'List' collection*

**Page 2**: *display items from 'List' collection* (user then selects an item from the list, returning the `_id`)

**Page 3**: *subscribe to 'Data' collection using `_id`* **<- STAY SUBSCRIBED FROM NOW ON, ON EVERY PAGE, WITHOUT THE USE OF IRON ROUTER**

I've messed around with `Template.subscribe`, `Template.onCreated` etc. but it's Friday and I'm sure this is elementary stuff so I thought I'd ask.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by 'without the use of iron:router? I don't understand why you would want to discard it when it can provide the solution.

Comment: iron:router causes issues with other parts of my app. I'm using `Template.dynamic` and a session variable for routing.

Comment: If the `Template.dynamic` issue is the only problem keeping you from using Iron Router to solve this problem, I would highly recommend using Iron Router along with the [iron:dynamic-template](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/dynamic-template) package. This will allow you to use Iron Router properly to solve this problem and be able to use dynamic templates as well.

Comment: thanks, I've solved it now but that looks as though it will be useful in future projects. if you don't mind, please take a look at my solution and let me know if there are any flaws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. **User logs in -> render `userLayout` -> set `currentPage` to
   `loading`**
2. **If user has already selected a project, set `currentPage` to `userSplash`** (else set `currentPage` to `userProjects` where they will select a project and then go to `userSplash`)

```
Template.userLayout.created = function() {
  Session.set('currentPage', 'loading');
  return Meteor.subscribe('projects', user.profile.company_id, function() {
    if (currentProject_id !== void 0) {
      return Session.set('currentPage', 'userSplash');
    } else {
      return Session.set('currentPage', 'userProjects');
    }
  });
};
```

3. **Render userSplash -> subscribe to required project data -> load dashboard when finished**

```
Template.userSplash.rendered = function() {
  return Meteor.subscribe('tasks', currentProject_id, function() {
    return Session.set('currentPage', 'userDashboard');
  });
};
```

([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28621744/3554602) answer provided some useful info)