# Template subscription fail with location

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, geolocation, publish-subscribe

I have a meteor app that is using d'burles:google-maps' and 'mdg:geolocation'. I have a list of places in a collection that I am doing a geospacial query to find places close to me, I have to run this on the server since the mini-mongo does not support it yet.

I'm publishing and am able to send back and forth parameters to narrow my search of places, but since the geolocation takes a second to get the user's location, I can't just subscribe right away, otherwise location is null and the query won't know what to do.

I think my problem is in where I am subscribing,

```
Meteor.subscribe('nearest', myLng, myLat, radius);
```

here is my code:

```
Template.map.onCreated(function() {
//****If i subscribe here, i get back results (if i use fixed location, geolocation won't have given me results yet)
    GoogleMaps.load();
    var self = this;
    Meteor.subscribe('nearest', myLng, myLat, );

    GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {
    //****If i subscribe here, it collection count will be 0
    //I need to subscribe HERE since this is when my geolocation will be provided
      var marker;
      console.log(Mycollection.find().count());


    });
});
```

This is my publish, which is run in a server folder:

```
Meteor.publish("nearest", function (lng, lat, dist) {
    return Mycollection.find( {loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ lng, lat ], dist/3963.2 ] } }} )
});
```

Anyone know why the second location is not subscribing correctly, or know a way to get a subscription based on the user's location reactively?

I've been searching and searching with no luck, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered running `GoogleMaps.ready()` in a `ready()` callback of `Meteor.subscribe`? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28621168/2805154

Comment: @MichelFloyd Googlemaps isn't what is breaking. I can't can't call meteor.subscribe until I have the user's location so I can fetch the appropriate locations for the map. The location service does not have a ready() to wait to subscribe and start the map. Unless I'm misunderstanding your advice?

Comment: AH ok so I figured out my problem. I was checking my map for new markers to see if my subscription inside the GoogleMaps.ready was working, however, i never drew them on the map! so after adding a ton of console.logs i figured out that i should redraw my map markers in a subscription.ready call back. BUT anyone with a better way to do this, I'm all ears.