# Meteor: Check if user read a message

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple chatbox in a meteor.js app. How would I check if the receiver of a message has seen it?

***In more general terms***: If a user is subsribed to a published collection does meteor have a built in way of detecting if that user gets the change?

*I know i'm kind of throwing a dart in the dark right now. If you're going to downvote me. At least point me in the right direction first :)*

[Similar question in 2012](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/521)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you are pointing from 2012 dosnt fit well on your question (maybe im wrong).

So do you want to make something like whatsapp, facebook, etc? the "seen" option?.

If the answer is yes, just puts `isSeen:boolean` flag on your document, and when the user clicks on the message check if the value is `true`/`false`, if its `false`, just set it to `true`.

Comment: Well it's a chatbox @Ethaan so the receiver could get new messages without clicking on the message box. I'm assuming the chatbox is open

Comment: Okay, well so the idea of the github issue can fit you, basically you need to have a collection named `UserConnection`, and this connection can have a field like `connectionts`, and then you are going to need to make a method, wich will work like a ping,this method will fire when the user login or rende some view like the master layout and will be executing each whathever seconds, looking for the userId, if the method find an userId, you will need to run an update to update all message < the connectionts as read or recived, soon the method stop getting the userId you will stop updating.

Comment: Okay sweet thanks I guess I will do that, Do you know of anywhere code base online that mentions someone using something similar? If not I'll just build it from scratch. @Ethaan Ethaan

Comment: actually that seems pretty heavy handed. Is there no way in meteor to check if the subscribed party received an update in a collection?

Comment: I think it was even you who pointed it out here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621132/meteor-subscribe-callback/28621168#28621168

Comment: I had to do something like this in cloak.ly, I set the `isSeen` boolean in an `onRendered` template handler that way I know that chat message has been drawn to the screen. Just knowing that the chat has been published to the client is not enough by itself, it doesn't guarantee it's been drawn.

Comment: After reading up on sub/publish i realize that your solution is very elegant and necessary. There likely is no other good way to do this. Fantastic solution. You are indeed the Queen of Meteor! @Ethaan Ethaan