# Template.subscriptionReady and Semantic UI Accordion Module

Tags: javascript, meteor, accordion, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui

I'm using Meteor with semantic-ui and i have a list of items i'd like to display in an accordion.

The accordion itself works perfectly fine until i wrap a `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` around it. than it does not work anymore.

The initialized accordion:

```
Template.register.rendered = function() {
    this.$('.ui.accordion').accordion();
}
```

**Question:** How can i use a semantic-ui accordion inside a `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` ?

Comment: Is it the case that the accordion needs to run some code when the template is rendered?

Comment: No, it just displays an index of entries sorted A - Z and for every letter ther is an accordion. Like: `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}} {{#each vocabulary}} // accordion code {{/each}} {{/if}}`. But if i wrap the 'each' in the subscriptionReady like this than the accordion does not open when i click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the subscription is not ready when the template renders, `$('.ui.accordion')` will not select anything since that element is inside the `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` block.

You need to wait for the subscription to be ready and then run `this.$('.ui.accordion').accordion()` at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621132/meteor-subscribe-callback) gave me the solution.