# Why can't I access React state within Tracker.Autorun?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

This one has me stumped, I'm using a Tracker.autorun function to listen for when my Mongo subscription is ready for querying (per suggestion on this previous [Meteor subscribe callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621132/meteor-subscribe-callback)). This seems to work ok in that it triggers after a couple seconds, indicating that the meteor subscription is ready. However when I try to check state within the Tracker.autorun function, this.state is undefined. Am I missing something obvious? Is there a better pattern for this? I've been running into more and more of these issues and am starting to ponder moving onto redux... Any advice greatly appreciated!!

```
export default class BulkMapWrapper extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  }

}

componentDidMount(){
const subscription =  Meteor.subscribe("allAuthors",{sort: {_id:-1}})
this.state = {
ready: subscription.ready(),
authorData: subscription
}

Tracker.autorun(function(){
if (subscription.ready()) {
  console.log("the subscription is ready");
  console.log(this.state)  //this is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am accessing my states in Meteor Tracker with the arrow function like this:

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    if (subscription.ready()) {
        console.log("the subscription is ready");
        console.log(this.state)  //this is undefined
     }
 });
```

Besides this I initialize my states in the constructor and then set them with this.setState() in `componentWillMount()`

Comment: Thanks grahan, this works perfectly! I suppose this is because arrow functions set the correct context for 'this'  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Glad it helped you. Yeah that's true, sorry that I missed this information. It's also helpful if you call Meteor methods from the client, and want to set the result as a state of your component. Then also use the arrow Funktion.